# cannot see my project in Unity after changing my mac

Tags: unity-game-engine

[image: My Unity looks like this for now]

Hello, it's been 4 days since I started Unity this year. I bought a new mac and tried to open my unity project, which I created on my old mac, with a new mac. I can see there are assets in the assets folder, but cannot see any game objects in my scene tab. I guess there is an Untitled game scene in the hierarchy tab, so it causes the problem(?). All I want to know is how to display my age objects in scene. Right now I cannot play the game even after I click the paly button on Unity. Sorry for the dumb question...

Comment: You're looking at a default scene. There are also no scenes in the project hierarchy (unless they are in another folder). Can you please clarify your question on `displaying my age objects`?

Comment: You are in the default "Untitled" scene ... Have you tried simply opening your own scene (it starts with "Leve..") from the assets below via double click? ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just something you get to know overtime:

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CreatingScenes.html

> When you create a new Unity project, your scene view
> displays a new Scene. This Scene is untitled and unsaved. The Scene is empty except for a Camera
> (called Main Camera) and a Light (called Directional Light).

When you create a project it'll make some user settings file that say 'open this scene by default when i open this project'. Since you moved the project onto a new machine, this setting was lost - and unity defaults to opening this untitled scene.

This also happens when you download a project from the internet.

Simply find the unity scene in the asset manager, and open it. It should then open your scene.

> To open a Scene in Unity, double-click the Scene Asset in the Project window. You must open a Scene in Unity to work on it.

[image]

Comment: @sommen thank you so much for explaining!